# Just added a new index, do I have to freeproccache?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

All,
Do you have to run dbcc freeproccache after you add an index to the system to make the optimizer aware of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the db engine is aware of and will build and use an index as soon as you create it.

You can see it in use by looking at a query plan for a query that selects a record based on the new index.

For instance, if the index is created on UserID, run a `SELECT * FROM Table Where UserID = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

When you create Index on any table,there will be B-Tree structure will be created in the DB on seperate space.And when you execute the query using the column on which you created index,then optimizer will automatically use that index from the STATASTICS info.

So you dont have to do anything after you create the index.

But when theere are page splits due to the inappropriate FILL FACTOR then you would look for INdex reorg or rebuild.